# Script to remove build configurations and schemes from xcodeproj file?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, command-line

Is there a way to remove the build configs and schemes from xcodeproj via a script/commandline without editing (project.pbxproj) in a text editor hoping it won't cross verify and impact the build.

I tried [`xcodeproj`](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj) which lets you read and represent the prj as yaml, I want one where I can edit the yaml and generate xcodeproj from it.

Also I tried removing schemes form `xcshareddata` still no performance improvement.

```
shell> xcodebuild -project myproject.xcodeproj -list

# output
Information about project "myproject":
    Targets:
        myproject
        myprojectTests
        ScreensForManPages
        UITestsCA
        ....
        ....
        UITestsUS

    Build Configurations:
        ae-debug
        ae-debug-another-condition
        ae-release
        ae-release-another-condition
        ...
        ...
        250+ build config in between
        ...
        ...
        zw-debug
        zw-debug-another-condition
        zw-release
        zw-release-another-condition

    If no build configuration is specified and -scheme is not passed then "ae-release-another-condition" is used.

    Schemes:
        myproject-ae-debug
        myproject-ae-debug-another-condition
        myproject-ae-release
        ...
        ...
        250+ schemes in between
        ...
        ...
        myproject-zw-debug
        myproject-zw-debug-another-condition
        myproject-zw-release
        myproject-zw-release-another-condition
```

Reason:

I recently inherited a project where there are 250+ build configurations and 250+ schemes. Unfortunately my work machine is good old mbp with hdd running osx mojave with xcode 10 is not capable of opening the project. (.xcodeproj file is about 10mb)

I can open the proj, but rainbow wheel every click, it takes more than 10 min to list the target, and I'm not aware of option in xcode to delete multiple config/schemes at once.

P.S:

[Apple script solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693482/how-do-i-remove-a-build-configuration-from-an-xcode-project-from-a-script) 
is not helpful xcode doesn't respond in timely fashion

Comment: Re: "I want one where I can edit the yaml and generate xcodeproj from it", what do you mean by this? It's possible to remove the schemes fairly easily (removing the `.xcscheme`'s is not enough, as `xcschememanagement.plist` needs to be edited also). To remove build configs you more or less need to manually edit the `project.pbxproj`

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I've removed schemes from my `xcshememanagement.plist` as well, no luck!

I found a tool called [xcodegen](https://github.com/yonaskolb/XcodeGen) which creates xcodeproj from a `yaml` configuration. Unfortunately it is not compatible with cocoapod's `xcodeproj show`

Comment: Keep in mind you need to have `Xcode` completely closed when you remove the schemes, otherwise if it's open while removing them then on exit it will not stick.

Answer (score 0):

**BEFORE YOU BEGIN**

> - <sub>**`Xcode` needs to be completely closed**.</sub>
> - <sub>**If you are going to manually edit your `Xcode` project *DEFINITELY*
>     make a backup before attempting this!**</sub>

**Schemes**:

Delete the scheme files you don't want inside of:

```
/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes
```

**Edit the management plist**:

```
/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/Username.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/xcschememanagement.plist
```

Inside the file remove the schemes you don't want (eg. `MyApp Custom`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>SchemeUserState</key>
    <dict>
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////// remove start
        <key>MyApp Custom.xcscheme_^#shared#^_</key>
        <dict>
            <key>orderHint</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////// remove end
        <key>MyApp.xcscheme_^#shared#^_</key>
        <dict>
            <key>orderHint</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>SuppressBuildableAutocreation</key>
    <dict>
        <key>AFDACD5A2209867B00004213</key>
        <dict>
            <key>primary</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Build Configurations**:

```
/MyApp/SomeProgram.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

I don't recommend manually editing this file, but rather remove the build configurations through `Xcode`, however if you're brave inside the file you'll see the configurations. You can also edit this file with a plist editor (plistbuddy, etc.) — remove the ones you don't want:

```
AFADF25C22269ABE000D354D =         {
            buildSettings =             {
     ...
         };
     isa = XCBuildConfiguration;
     name = Custom;
};
```

You'll also see the corresponding `UID` grouped with other configurations:

```
AFDACD542209865600004213 =         {
            buildConfigurations =             (
                AFDACD552209865600004213,
                AFDACD562209865600004213,
                AFADF25C22269ABE000D354D ////// remove
            );
            defaultConfigurationIsVisible = 0;
            defaultConfigurationName = Release;
            isa = XCConfigurationList;
        };
```

Now when you open up your `.xcodeproj` the changes should be reflected.